# SVG textPath not attached to the linked path after FabricJS import?

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I have the following SVG which works fine on it's own: http://jsfiddle.net/bL3k48jn/1/

However, when imported with `fabric.loadSVGFromString` the text is no long attached to the path, and the font styles are lost.

**The SVG**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="500px" height="500px">

  <path id="textPath" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="yellow"
    d="
    M 250 -250
    m 0, 250
    a -250,250 0 1,0 0,500
    a 250,-250 0 1,0  0,-500
    "
  />

  <text fill="black" font-family = "arial" text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath startOffset="50%" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" xlink:href="#textPath">Happy Birthday Dad!</textPath>
  </text>      

</svg>
```

You should see a circle with some text following the bottom edge of the curve.

The code I'm using to import the SVG is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hnzgy940/2/

**The Javascript**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// This is the SVG as a single line
var str = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="500px" height="500px"><path id="text_path" d="M 250 -250 m 0,250 a -250,250 0 1,0 0,500 a 250,-250 0 1,0 0,-500"  fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="yellow"/><text font-family="arial" text-anchor="middle"><textPath startOffset="50%" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" xlink:href="#text_path">Happy Birthday Dad!</textPath></text></svg>';

fabric.loadSVGFromString(str, function(objects, options) {
    svg_text = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options)

    svg_text.set({
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    left: canvas.width / 2,
    top: canvas.height / 2
    });

    svg_text.setCoords();
    canvas.add(svg_text);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

It appears to be ignoring the `xlink:href` attribute, on the `<textPath>` element, along with the font styles, which I guess means it might just be ignoring the entire `<textPath>` element, but I can't see why.

I had a problem previously where the text wouldn't show at all, but I think this may have been because I didn't have the correct `xmlns` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Text Paths are not supported yet in Fabric, but there is a branch:

https://github.com/lirmont/fabric.js/tree/Curve-Text

Also, see the conversation:

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/729